# No such file or directory error when using gulp command ?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gulp

I am using ubuntu, I have installed npm and Nodejs in order to install gulp. I installed gulp globally using the following command `npm install --global gulp`, After that I have installed glup in my project using the following command: `npm install --save-dev gulp`. However, When I try to run the command `gulp` I receive this error `bash: /usr/local/bin/gulp: No such file or directory`. I also receive the same error when I try to run this command: `gulp --version`

Solutions I attempted:
I have run this command `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` in order to get  gulpfile.js to be executed though. However I still Receive the same error.

Answer (score 9):

I solved this problem by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node 
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs 
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```